# Power BI how to create new column in date table based on conditions and reference to another table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a date table called 'dDate', it looks like below:

```
Date        
01/01/2020
02/01/2020
03/01/2020
```

I have another table called 'Calendar', which looks like below. Note that not all dates are present in this table.

```
Date        Holiday
01/01/2020  1
03/01/2020  0
```

I want to add a column 'HolidayDate' to the dDate table, where, for a particular date, a value of 1 is given if 'Holiday'=1 from Calendar, else a value of 0. So the HolidayDate column looks for the date in the Calendar table, checks if holiday is 1 and returns 1 if it is.

So the output in dDate table should look like:

```
Date        HolidayDate
01/01/2020  1
02/01/2020  0
03/01/2020  0
```

I want to add a new column and specify a formula which achieves the above. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Calendar and dDate has relationship, you can create the following calculated column in dDate

`HolidayfromCalendar = RELATED('Calendar'[Holiday])`

If Calendar and dDate has no relationship, you can create the following calculated column in dDate

```
HolidayfromCalendar =
CALCULATE (
    MAXX (
        FILTER ( 'Calendar', 'Calendar'[Date] = MAX ( dDate[Date] ) ),
        'Calendar'[Holiday]
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create a simple relationship between you source table with the date and the table with the calendar, then you can use the holiday date for the source table and PowerBI will make the join for you. You don't need to "copy" the holiday indicator across. In fact, the holiday indicator belongs with the calendar table, since this is effectively your date dimension in a [Kimball](https://www.kimballgroup.com/2003/01/fact-tables-and-dimension-tables/) model.

As per comment, if you model is not yours to change, or you have painted yourself in to a bit of a corner with complexity, you can resort to using [LOOKUPVALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/lookupvalue-function-dax) to pull the data across. Keep in mind this may have a performance impact on huge data sets.

Comment: The sample data I've given omits columns for the sake of clarity. In reality, these two tables are connected with the date column, but the Calendar table has an additional column 'Calendar Code', which has a many-to many relationship with another table. For this reason, I am not able use a slicer from the calendar table directly.

Comment: Suggest you refactor you model to get to an expanded version to create 1-to-many relationships.

Comment: Its a good idea, but it seems too complex if I can achieve this with a formula.

Comment: Try LOOKUPVALUE https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/lookupvalue-function-dax